# What does 'g' in switching converter input voltage \$V_g\$ stand for?

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, terminology, symbol

I'm studying switching converters and the input voltage of a Buck, Boost, or whatever is designated as \$V_g\$. I've racked my brain (and also searched Google), but I can't work out what the 'g' could possibly stand for.

[image]

I suppose it's one of those things that is so obvious once known that no one thinks to mention it.

What does the 'g' stand for? Why isn't it just \$V_{in}\$ or something straightforward like that?

Comment: I guess it is an arbitrary choice, it could stand for "V generator". Although I have seen many switched converter schematics, I think this is the first time I see a "Vg".

Comment: It could stand for "*g*uess what this stands for"...?

Comment: @FakeMoustache - Ah, yes, it could be an artifact of the main text I'm studying, *Fundamentals of Power Electronics, 2ed*; Erickson. I notice now that you mention it that Maniktala in *Switching Power Supplies A-Z* uses \$V_{IN}\$ quite consistently. I like your hypothesis of \$V_{generator}\$, I'm going to use that one in my head as I'm reading Erickson :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the author (Robert W. Erickson) himself!:

> Many of the early papers in this field called it \$V_g\$, and the name stuck. I think 'g' does indeed stand for 'generator'. Certainly a more meaningful name would be preferable in an actual application.

https://www.coursera.org/learn/power-electronics/discussions/J1AxBsR2EeW_BRLjpUoXzQ

Good guess @FakeMoustache :)